# MS Azure AD Connect: Download on a Mac for VM?

Tags: azure

I am using Azure AD to test SSO for a customer, and it appears that I have to download AD Connect. I am on a Mac, but intend to test in a Windows 10, MS AD VM in Azure. How do I incorporate AD Connect into my VM when my Mac won't open the download file?

Answer (score 0):

AD Connect is required in order to sync directory information between on-prem AD and AAD.  You can (but might violate security best practices) run AD Connect on the Domain Controller itself.  Once setup, users will sync between your on-prem environment and AAD.  You can then test SSO.

I'm not sure where you got the requirement that AD Connect needs to be installed on your mac.  It doesn't, it just needs to be installed on a windows server with access to the domain as well as internet access to sync with AAD.

Comment: Thank you! Ok we don't have a Windows server, other than the MS Azure WIdowsVM. How do I install AzureADConnect on the MS Azure Windows VM?

Comment: Same way you would install it on a regular VM or a physical.  Download the installer and run through the wizard.